# How to select optimal number of components for NMF in python sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, nmf

There is not a built-in function in python's sklearn to do this.

In my [research](https://towardsdatascience.com/using-nmf-to-classify-companies-a77e176f276f) I found out that a "precision score" err(components) can be calculated via

[image]

The optimal number of components will have the minimum err(c).

Given the below test code, how can the precision score be implemented in python?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.decomposition import NMF
X = np.random.rand(40, 100) # create matrix for NMF
c = 4
model = NMF(n_components=c, init='random', random_state=0)
W = model.fit_transform(X)
H = model.components_
```

Comment: the transposition in the formula seems a bit off...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the transposition in your formula since sklearn seems to transpose already H but this should do the trick

```
err = np.linalg.norm(X - W @ H)**2/np.linalg.norm(X)**2
print(err)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the built in function "reconstruction error" as follows:

err = model.reconstruction_err_